# Selective merge of a bunch of changes

Tags: git

At the beginning of the week I branched my development branch so I could work on a trade show demonstration. Along the way, we discovered some issues and I worked on some things that need to make their way into the development branch (and ultimately main release).

What I need to do is look at the new branch and select the changes that I want to merge to development. Please note that some commits contain changes that need be merged and some that should be ignored.

I'm new to Git so can somebody explain the concepts/terminology around what I need to do please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the whole commit in the new branch, you can use the `cherry-pick`

```
git cherry-pick <commit-sha>
```

You can use `git checkout --patch <commit-sha>` to pick individual hunks from the commit. This will provide you with an interactive shell where you can perform several task for each hunk..

```
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]? ?
y - apply this hunk to index and worktree
n - do not apply this hunk to index and worktree
q - quit; do not apply this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - apply this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not apply this hunk nor any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

You can selectively pick hunks from individual files too.

```
git checkout --patch <commit-sha> -- <file-name>
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thanks. Only thing is, when repeating after a number of commits, I am prompted with all the previously ignored hunks. Is there a way to avoid this? This is in reference to the second command you provided.

Answer (score 2):

check out `git cherry-pick` which allows you to incorporate commits from one branch into another.

if you only want to use parts of a commit, you can do so by fixing the commit after cherry-picking it.
i usually use `git gui`'s *amend last commit* functionality for fixing commit-messages and committed chunks.

```
$ git cherry-pick workbranch~5
$ git gui
// fix what needs fixing
$ git cherry-pick workbranch~4
// we leave out workbranch~3 entirely
$ git cherry-pick workbranch~2
// ...
```

with `cherry-picking`  you can also change the order of the commits...

in any case, you should make it your practice to make small atomic commits (*commit often!*); this way, you minimize the need to amend commits afterwards.

Comment: Cool, and also specify the chunks within a commit?